# Mageia - how do I setup a KVM for Windows gaming?

Tags: linux, kvm, virt-manager

Okay so I setup a KVM using Virt-Manager, Iset it to 7443 out of 8GB RAM, Got it to emulate my CPU fully, everything worked fine, but I can't get my GPU to unbind from the host to the guest, So is there any script that is around to help?

I will post below all error codes I have encountered while attempting to create the machine.

```
 Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devicesTraceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 91, in cb_wrapper    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 127, in tmpcb    callback(*args, **kwargs)  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1260, in startup    self._backend.create()  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 866, in create    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)libvirtError: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices
```

That above is when I attempt to run the KVM with a PCI device, no matter the device it still happens.

My lspci output

```
[root@localhost xdroidie626]# lspci00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870]01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]
```

Virsh output

```
[root@localhost xdroidie626]# virsh nodedev-dumpxml pci_0000_01_00_0<device>  <name>pci_0000_01_00_0</name>  <path>/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0</path>  <parent>pci_0000_00_01_0</parent>  <driver>    <name>radeon</name>  </driver>  <capability type='pci'>    <domain>0</domain>    <bus>1</bus>    <slot>0</slot>    <function>0</function>    <product id='0x6738'>Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870]</product>    <vendor id='0x1002'>Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]</vendor>  </capability></device>[root@localhost xdroidie626]# virsh nodedev-dettach pci_0000_01_00_0error: Failed to detach device pci_0000_01_00_0error: invalid argument: neither VFIO nor kvm device assignment is currently supported on this system
```

And the output Virsh gives when I attempt to unbind the device

```
[root@localhost xdroidie626]# virsh nodedev-dettach pci_0000_01_00_0error: Failed to detach device pci_0000_01_00_0error: invalid argument: neither VFIO nor kvm device assignment is currently supported on this system
```

I do apologise about the small amount of information but I don't know what to do next.

All I want the KVM for is to run games via windows, adding to that I can snapshot back if need be (Virus etc)

My specs for the system are as posted
G1 Sniper M3 Z77 motherboard
i5 2500 3.3Ghz CPU
AMD 6870 1GB
8GB RAM
Samsung 840 SSD 120GB 
500GB 7200.12RPM drive

Any solutions to the errors posted, and to my entire problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your hardware doesn't support PCI passthrough.

Comment: So does the xfx amd radeon 6870 not support passthrough?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I need no clarification. The errors say it clearly : `unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices
`

Answer (score 1):

To enable IOMMU on the kernel for Intel processors, pass `intel_iommu=on` boot parameter on your Linux.

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`  add `intel_iommu=on` at the end of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="...."`
- do `sudo update-grub`
- then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to activate Intel/AMD IOMMU from the BIOS menu, after that you need to enable IOMMU in the grub: Edit the config file (e.g. `nano /etc/default/grub`) and set

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"
  ```

  or

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet amd_iommu=on iommu=pt"
  ```
- Then you need to find the PCI ID of your GPU using the following command :

  ```
  lspci -vnn
  ```

  You can find the PCI IDs just like this, then add them to your grub (if you want) or you can add then only when you want to use them in `virt-manager`, and after that you need to load the `vfio` drivers and block `nonvae`, then you can add the GPU to the VM.

To load VFIO modules at boot:

- Edit `/etc/modules` to contain the following lines

  ```
  vfio
  vfio_iommu_type1
  vfio_pci
  vfio_virqfd
  ```
- Save file and close
- Execute

  ```bash
  echo "options vfio_iommu_type1 allow_unsafe_interrupts=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/iommu_unsafe_interrupts.conf
  echo "options kvm ignore_msrs=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/kvm.conf
  echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
  update-initramfs -u
  reboot
  ```

To check if IOMMU is working, run

```
dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means PCI passthrough is not supported by the hardware. It might simply be turned off - check if you have VT-d enabled in the BIOS. If you don't even have the option to enable/disable it, then you don't have it.

In any case, gaming in VMs is still a bad idea at this day and age.

Comment: Vt-d is enabled already and why so? Pci binding works well no